# How to repair an Exchange mailbox database in a dirty shutdown state?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

My Exchange database is in a dirty shutdown state, and I don’t have a backup.
There is a corupt log file named e00.log. How can I repair the Exchange Database?

Comment: Questions like this are generally discouraged unless you can show what you have tried already and what resources you have already exhausted. You're generally going to get a "LMGTFY" response if you just drop a straight "how do I" question here without showing your effort. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the ESEUtil (and a search engine) to repair your database if no backup is available. You can read up on the specifics of [eseutil.exe on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996436(v=exchg.65).aspx), but the *basics* are as follows:

> - Run Eseutil /P
> - After Eseutil /P completes successfully, run Eseutil /D
> - After Eseutil /D completes successfully, run Isinteg –fix –test alltests

Now, instead of re-writing the entire process, I'll point you to a few good step-by-step guides with more detail:

[Exchange Server Database Corruption and Dirty Shutdown Scenarios](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-server-database-corruption-and-dirty-shutdown-scenarios/) - Explains how this happened.

[Repair Exchange DB After Dirty Shutdown](https://alexvoropaev.jimdo.com/my-articles/exchange/repair-exchange-db-after-dirty-shutdown/) - A very detailed step-by-step guide.

[Why Exchange Databases Might Remain Dirty After ESEUTIL /R Recovery](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2012/09/06/why-exchange-databases-might-remain-dirty-after-eseutil-r-recovery/) - Additional valuable reading on the topic.

**Be aware** that this process takes a lot of time and a lot of free disk space. PLEASE read the linked TechNet article and possibly other resources before running these commands. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since Log play import role after the Main database, as transaction logs carries data that even database might not have and thus they play an important role in the recovery of Exchange database at times of failures. Without log files, DB would be inconsistent and most probably unusable.

Since Exchange Database hold two State: **“Dirty Shutdown and Clean Shutdown”** depend on whether the database is in **“Consistent or "Inconsistent”** state

**Inconsistent DB:** If transactions are waiting to be written to the database but the Server shuts down accidentally (due to any reason), the DB remains attached with the LOG files. In this case, the pages for modification in the memory are marked as Dirty and this is the reason the DB in this scenario is called to be in Dirty shutdown state, similar to above case:

Verify the state of the database, **ESEutil /mh** command can be used:

Two ways in which Exchange Server performs recovery of Exchange database the when **log file is corrupt**

**Soft Recovery:** this recovery is performed against offline copythe  of database. Here, the recovery has to be processed manually usthe ing ESEutil tool. the For manual replay of log files, the syntax is:

**Hard Recovery:** Process lead to replaying the log file and can be processed with "Last Backup Set" It is similar to soft recovery but is different from it in the aspect that instead of Checkpoint file, Restore.env file can be used to replay log files.

**Ref:**http://www.exchangerecover.com/blog/recover-exchange-database-without-log-files.html

Answer (score 0):

When database shows Dirty Shutdown, it display which log file is required to mount the database & bring the database to a consistent state. But in some cases, database cannot bring back into a clean state by playing log file because log files are corrupt or missing. In this case, you need to use eseutil/p to repair the database, Run [Eseutil command](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/168508-how-to-repair-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how) against a copy of the database.

when the database is repaired the use eseutil/d switch to defrag the DB to ensure that it is healthy. then move the mailboxes to a new database.

**Important Pointers:**

1. You need at least 110-120% additional disk space
2. If your DB size is 2GB, then you need up to 2.2GB for recovered DB.